# Selenium on Twitter with Python. I can't get the button with any locating elements of selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, twitter, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to click spam button with Selenium on Python. But when I go to three dotes on someone profile i can click report @thisperson then I can't click "It’s suspicious or spam" button. I'm going crazy because I tried every way for pulling button with selenium. For example, find_element_by_id, path, css selector, class name and They don't work. Please help me,show me a way, enlighten me.
[image]
My Python code for clicking button:

```
spam_button = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//form[@id="report_webview_form"]/button[2]/span')
```

here is html tags for this button :
[image]

I tried a complicated path for clicking button :

```
spam_button = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div/div[2]/div/iframe/#document/html/body/div/div/form/button[2]/span')
```

I don't know how I write "document" tag. So I get the error.
I tried find_element_by_id:

```
spam_button = browser.find_element_by_id('spam-btn')
browser.implicitly_wait(5)
ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(spam_button).click(spam_button).perform()
```

And I got the error "Unable element"
I am lost. How can I click the button with selenium ?

My whole code:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
url ="https://twitter.com/ANYACCOUNT"

browser.get(url)
time.sleep(1)
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='/login']").click()
time.sleep(1)
username = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div/div[2]/form/div/div[1]/label/div/div[2]/div/input')
time.sleep(1)
username.send_keys("MYNICKNAME")
time.sleep(1)
password = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/label/div/div[2]/div/input')
time.sleep(1)
password.send_keys("MYPASSWORD")
time.sleep(1)
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div/div[2]/form/div/div[3]/div/div/span/span').click()
time.sleep(1)
button = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/span')
browser.implicitly_wait(5)
ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(button).click(button).perform()
time.sleep(1)
sikayet = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div/div[5]/div[2]/div/span')
browser.implicitly_wait(5)
ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(sikayet).click(sikayet).perform()
time.sleep(1)
#spam_button = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div/div[2]/div/iframe/#document/html/body/div/div/form/button[2]/span')
#browser.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@id="spam-btn"]')
#browser.implicitly_wait(5)
#ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(spam_button).click(spam_button).perform()
wait = WebDriverWait(browser,10 )
spam_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "spam-btn")))
time.sleep(1)
spam_button.click()
```

I tried other ways as mentioned in below comment and I got this error everytime .
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using explicit wait instead of implicit:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "spam-btn")))
spam_button = browser.find_element_by_id('spam-btn')
spam_button.click()
```

OR,

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#spam-btn>div")))
spam_button = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#spam-btn>div')
spam_button.click()
```

**Update:**
You need to switch to iframe.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/snap/bin/chromium.chromedriver')
driver.get('https://twitter.com/apiontkovsky/status/1385614545947820037')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)

# Authorise here
# ...

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".css-1dbjc4n.r-18u37iz.r-15zivkp .css-1dbjc4n.r-xoduu5 svg")))
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".css-1dbjc4n.r-18u37iz.r-15zivkp .css-1dbjc4n.r-xoduu5 svg").click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'Report')]")))
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Report')]").click()
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".r-1yadl64.r-16y2uox")))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#spam-btn>div")))
spam_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#spam-btn>div')
spam_button.click()
```

Comment: Thank u , I tried this codes  but I got the error for more than 10 times.The error is TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: Can you copy the whole html code of the page and put it to the question?

Comment: I colud put the image , I couldn't whole code because it is so much

Comment: ok, i'll try myself. please describe test steps more clearly. which twit, which button to click?

Comment: ok. I will try and thanks so much .1 - describing libraries : import time
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

Comment: Ok, I've made a test account. WIll try to do it)

Comment: best of this , I will put whole of my code below of the question you can look .

Comment: To find iframe locator use css and class names with .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231557/discussion-between-vitaliis-and-tugba-ozkan).

Comment: dear vitaliis I added last error to end of my questiıon .I tried and tried and I  got  same error ,I think error and me like a family now.@vitaliis

Comment: unfortunately , no